# How to print %s in C?

Tags: c, printf

I want to print `"%SomeString%"` in C.

Is this correct?

```
printf("%%s%",SomeString);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, %% outputs %, so the right syntax is:

```
printf("%%%s%%",string);
```

Answer (score 9):

No.

Use `%%%s%%`

Comment: explanation: %% escapes to a % character. %s is a control code.

Answer (score 5):

```
printf("%%%s%%", string);
```

Should output a % each side.

Answer (score 3):

This solution absolves you from knowing how special printf characters like '%' or '\' should be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char str[]="MyString";
    printf("%c%s%c",'%',str,'%');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit overkilling? `printf` has an appropriate escape charachter for `%` so why not using it? If the problem is remembering it... well, it's just a Google search away.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I wouldn't use this if I knew the %% or \\ sequences but it's still good to know in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, its good to realize you can do this. I think it would help people understand what printf is doing. But don't do it in production. :)

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe you are correct - it pushes more elements that it should on the stack, it keeps memory occupied with the parameters ('%', '%'are constants that must be held in memory before being pushed on the stack for the *printf functions)

Answer (score 0):

You can print a string like this: 
printf("%s", SomeString);

It should work!

Comment: The point was to output % sign at left and at right of the formatted string.

Comment: Oh ok, thought he made a mistake in the post!

Answer (score -1):

Try %%%s%%

```
printf("%%%s%%",yourstring);
```

The output will be in the format %yourstring%.

Inside the printf(), %% is equal to printing %

Explanation: Characters like , % etc. are used for some other purposes. So, in order to print them, add the same character once more i.e. if you want to display a single '%', make it '%%' in the printf.